# Need help in understand C code

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

Hi I need some help in understand some C code:

```
#if 0
   some C code 1
#elif 0
   static int8 arry[10];
#pragma Align_to(32, arry)
   ASSERT(((int8ptr_t)arry) & 15) == 0)
#else
   ASSERT(((int8ptr_t)arry) & 15) == 0)
#endif
```

My questions:

1. Is only the `#else` part compiled?
2. What is the meaning of `#pragma Align_to(32, arry)` in the `#elif 0` case?

Comment: I believe it's `#pragma`. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html

Comment: It's `pragma` instead of `pramga`.

Comment: Whether it's pragma or pramga isn't relevant... the `#elif 0` means it is ignored. Only the `#else` is compiled as the OP surmises.

Comment: @KScottPiel Is that required? I've known compilers that process all #pragmas irrespective of whether or not they're in a #if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `#else` part is what is compiled.

---

The `#pragma` directive is a compiler specific directive.  As you compiler was not specified, it *could* mean anything.

In your case `#pragma Align_to(32, arry)`, likely tells the compiler to insure variable 'arry' is place in memory on a 32 byte boundary.  This is typically for performance reasons or compatibility concerns.  You may also want to look into the keyword `__attribute__` use to control similar variable attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Actually better way to answer is ask compiler - use `g++ -E` or MSVC: `cl /EP` to print what is really compiled

Comment: Programming by experimentation? I'm not convinced that asking a compiler will give any definitive answer--unlike reading the C language spec/Standard will.

Comment: @Jens my answer related to first part of question - instead of solving puzzle *"what part of preprocessor monster is compiled"* I'd prefer to generate expanded file

Comment: +1 Fair enough, but we need to be aware of the experimentation pitfalls in general.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to 1: Yes, but note that even the parts within `#if 0` etc. must consist of valid preprocessing tokens. This means that this will fail with a diagnostic:

```
#if 0
That's what C is all about
#endif
```

because there's an unterminated character constant introduced by the lone `'`. Same goes for unterminated string literals.

Answer to 2: The `pragma` is a hint to the compiler that the address of `arry` shall be aligned on a multiple of 32.